# Regular Expression Matching Java

Tags: java, regex, expression

I'm working on a regular expression matching issue. The thing is, I want to match a string with more than 7 (any characters, including number, letter, special character). I'm using the below expression (I remove the head and end symbol) but doesn't work as I thought. Any idea about this?

```
"((\\w|W){7,})"
```

Java Code:

```
        final String VALID_REGEX =
            "^((\\w{2,6})" // 2 to 6 characters
                    + "(?:[\\r\\n]{1,3})" // 1 or 3 carriage returns
                    + "([\\w\\W]{7,})" // equal to or more than 7 characters or spaces
                    + "(?:[\\r\\n]{1,3})" // 1 or 3 carriage returns
                    + "(?:[\\w\\W])*"; // Any text
    Pattern regExPattern = Pattern.compile(VALID_REGEX, Pattern.DOTALL);
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/hqu/Downloads/test.txt")));
    Matcher noMatcher = regExPattern.matcher(content);
    if(noMatcher.matches())
        System.out.println("match");
    else
        System.out.println("not match");
```

Input:

Not match [image]

Match [image]

Comment: `W` only matches `W`. `\w` matches letters, digits and `_`. Now, what are the precise requirements? Could you provide some sample input?

Comment: You can use this one `\\b\\w{7,}\\b`

Comment: *More than 7 digits or spaces* sounds rather vague. `s.matches("(?s)(?:[^\\d\\s]*[\\d\\s]){8}.*")`?

Comment: `[\d\s]{7,}` Tested [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: Oh, why use a regex at all here? Can't you check it with `length()`? Ok, just `s.matches("(?s).{7,}")` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wikor. Actually, any characters, including number, letter, special character.

Comment: But why regex? Can't you check it with `length()`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because we have a complex expression matching, this one is part of it.

Comment: Ok, then probably `(?s:.{7,})` is what will help. It would help if you posted the whole expression.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Thanks. Actually, I want it to match everything with length of 7.

Comment: `[\w\W]{7,}` How about now? Rememer to check the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) and a [place you could test really fast](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. But the expression is kind of a secret to our clients. Something like this       + "((\\w| ){7,*})?" // equal or more than 7 digits or spaces
      + "(?:[\\r\\n]{1,3})" // 1 or 3 carriage returns

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado `[\w\W]{7,}` is the same as `(?s:.{7,})` but worse since it is a workaround, a custom character class is less efficient than the built-in `.` with the DOTALL mode on.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Well...I tested a string with length less than 7, it still matches...

Comment: @TommyQu That means the issue is with the other part of your super-secret pattern. Please obfuscate it somehow, and post it. I suspect you have some alternative there that matches less than 7 chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, just learned a little bit on how to improve eficiency of a regex :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks guys..I tried on some online tools, it works. However, it just doesn't work for my specific input. I will try and test it out.

Comment: @TommyQu There is no point asking a question without showing what you have trouble with. It is a question that only you can answer. Off-topic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Posted two sample inputs,

Comment: @TommyQu If you want to match 2+ lines, why require a second line break? Replace the second [`(?:[\r\n]{1,3})` with `(?:[\r\n]{0,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/FYI7VJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but replace

"([\w\W]{7,})"

with

"([\w| ]{7,})"

works for my test cases.